# MySQL dump using PHP exec works. Can't import or copy, however

Tags: php, mysql, exec

This is working:

```
exec('mysqldump --single-transaction --user=myusername --password=mypassword --host=localhost mydb > /home/path/public_html/a.sql');

exec('mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword --execute="drop database mydevdb;"');

exec('mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword --execute="create database mydevdb;"');
```

The SQL file gets created with the queries in it from the live db, in the right place, the dev db is dropped and recreated. Note that the first exec only works with `--single-transaction`. But the last step, below, is not working. It creates the first table, with no data, and no other tables. I've tried it with and without `--single-transaction`.

```
exec('mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword --host=localhost mydevdb < /home/path/public_html/a.sql');
```

What I really want is to clone one database to another within the same MYSQL instance via PHP.  This doesn't work either:

```
exec('mysqldump --user=myusername --password=mypassword --host=localhost mydb | mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword --host=localhost mydevdb');
```

So I am trying to dump and then import. Any ideas?

Comment: have you checked return values from the exec() call? look for output? checked that mysqldump and mysql are in the path of whatever shell PHP is invoking? Executed all those commands yourself on the CLI?

Comment: Thanks Marc - can't I assume the mysqldump and mysql are in the path since those commands both work as shown in the first group of statements?

Comment: The code in your last statement should work provided mydevdb exists (just tested on my system). While I would also assume that mysql and mysqldump are on the path, running it from the CLI as Marc suggests will show you any errors that are generated.

Comment: Thanks all. Turns out I didn't have permissions for lock tables on the destination db for the user. Fixed and working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its been to late to answer here but there is a way to Clone database using below command.

> exec('mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword --execute="drop
>   database new_dbname"');
>
> exec('mysql --user=myusername --password=mypassword --execute="create
>   database new_dbname"');
>
> exec("mysqldump --events --ignore-table=mysql.events -u $myusername
>   -p'$mypassword' $existing_db_name | mysql -u $myusername -p'$mypassword' -C $new_dbname");