# Export/Import Full Database also individual tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am stucked with  a situation where i have to list all the tables from the database given. Then the user can select any table to export or the full database.

I used show all tables.

```
$query = "SHOW TABLES FROM $DBNAME";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
$tables = array();
while($sql1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
  $name = $sql[0];
  $tables[] = $name;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($tables);
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

But the array is with no name but having the same number of elements as the number of tables.

Any help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$name = $sql[0];` with `$name = $sql1[0];`

Comment: ohh fine. But can you please help me how to export mysql table into sql file by table name ?

Comment: the easiest way would be to use mysql dump ... have a look here : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9306/how-do-you-mysqldump-specific-tables

Comment: I have tried this : mysqldump -u root -p new > sugarcrm.sql But it is saying syntax error 

My username is root and password is empty

Comment: for a single table you should use something like `mysqldump -uUSERNAME -pPASWORD DATABASE TABLE_NAME > file.sql`

Comment: i used this but still givinf syntax error 

mysqldump -uroot -p new new_options > file.sql

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -uroot -p new new_options > file.sql' at line 1

Comment: hmmm... this is a command and you need to execute it through command line or if you using php try `exec("mysqldump -uroot -p new new_options > file.sql")`

Comment: you can read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838741/mysql-dump-using-php-exec-works-cant-import-or-copy-however

Answer (score 0):

It could be like this ..

```
    $query = "SHOW TABLES FROM $DBNAME";
    $sql = mysql_query($query);
    (int) $i = 0;
    while ($sql1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $name[] = $sql1;
        $tables[] = $name[$i][0];
        $i++;
   }
   print_r($tables);
    echo '</pre>';
    exit;
```

Comment: I have tried this :
mysqldump -u root -p new > sugarcrm.sql

But it is saying syntax error

Comment: try this one "mysqldump -u user_name -p password Name_of_database >file_for_write.sql
"

Comment: i have also tried with the same but it is working well here ... please recheck your code.